# Jupyter notebook "download as python"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've been searching everywhere for this but somehow I can't seem to find it.

If you download code from Jupyter notebook and download it as python (.py),

then does the computer create a windows notepad for the .py file? (Yes I'm using windows not mac)

This is a pretty simple question but I really wish to know if this is a normal thing for windows...

When I download code in Jupyter notebook as python (.py), it is downloaded as a notepad.

Is this what it's supposed to do??

Comment: A file isn't "downloaded as a notepad". It's downloaded as a .py file which is a text file conforming to [Python syntax rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics). Whether or not *your* copy of Windows opens .py files in Notepad by default is *your* decision as the computer owner. *My* copy of Windows is set up to open .py files in a professional tool for Python development that has more features than Notepad itself, and my co-worker is set up that her computer asks her what to do when she double-clicks a Python file.

Comment: downloaded as notepad means? What is the extension of that file that is getting downloaded??

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your default application for files is set as Notepad in windows. That's why it shows to open with Notepad. Since the file comes with *.py extension it will also consider to open in notepad because ultimately *.py is a file type. You can try open with option to open your favorite python editor to work on the file.

Comment: So my question is, that's not a problem in itself right? Since notepad can still be used as a text editor... I just wanted to know if .py file that opens with Notepad will have any technical problems as a .py file.

Comment: No. Usually notepad is not supporting for python syntax's. I'm not suggesting to edit .py files from notepad. You can use python syntax supporting editors like pycharm and notepad++.